# assertion.softAssert is not a function while implementing soft-assertion in typescript based protractor framework

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, node-modules, assert

> **TypeError: assertion.softAssert is not a function**

I have imported a package called [soft-assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-assert) via npm.
For adding this in my project I ran

```
npm i soft-assert -g --save-dev
```

I have added code like this here:-

```
 import * as assertion from "../../soft-assert/lib/assertion";

 await assertion.softAssert(await this.headerOversightrequirements.getText(), AdminPanelData.lblOversightRequirements, AdminPanelData.lblOversightRequirements,[]);

 await assertion.deepAssert(await this.headerAdminPanel.getText(), AdminPanelData.lblAdminPanel, header is displayed,[]);
```

I am using **protractor** as a automation framework, cucumber as a **BDD** tool, **typescript** as a scripting language and **npm** for installing the dependencies.
Everytime I am running my code it shows the function is there. I can go to the node_module/soft-assert package which is there and installed and see the assertion file there, not sure why this issue is happening.  I can go to the method implementation but while execution I am getting the error as soon as executor reaches the line where I have implemented the soft/deep assert.

Answer (score -1):

Is the relative location of assertion in import statement is correct? I am able to use below in my code, which resides in root level of project.

```
import * as assertion from "../lib/assertion"; 

assertion.softAssert({a:123}, {a:12}, "Failure error message 1", []);
assertion.softAssert({a:123}, {a:123}, "Failure error message 2", []);
assertion.softAssertAll();
```